# Deleting and Adding nodes inside a href

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an object:

```
<a href="#" data-role="leaf">
   <i class="icon-plane"></i> 
   Projects
</a>
```

I want to implement select and deselect by deleting `<i class="icon-plane"></i>` inside the object. (The click event is handled by the framework and I know how to use it.)

Btw how to check that there is a `<i></i>` inside this `a` element?

I tried to use `node.append('<i class="name"></i>')`, but that yields:

```
<a href="#" data-role="leaf">
   Projects
   <i class="icon-plane"></i> 
</a>
```

I hope the icon is before `Project`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `.prepend()` instead:

```
node.prepend('<i class="name"></i>')
```

Also if you want to check if there's an `<i>` element inside your `<a>`, you can use `.has()` + `length` (it'll return 0 if it doesn't and the number of matching elements otherwise) like this:

```
node.has('i').length
```

If you want to remove the `<i>` inside your `<a>`, you should do it like this:

```
node.find('i').remove()
```

Comment: This a *DUH* type question :-P `+1`

Comment: And that was a _RUDE_ type comment.  Ignore him John . . . most people here are happy to help you without putting you down.

Comment: Thanks! How to remove this <i> tag?

Comment: @JohnSket don't worry, it's just a matter of studying and practicing, just don't give up...

Answer (score 1):

Try using [`prepend`](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) instead. Append adds the new tag at the end of the div, while prepend adds it to the very beginning of the div.

```
node.append('<i class="name"></i>')
```